# Как изменить sprite при нажатии клавиши?

Tags: c++, sfml

Столкнулся с проблемой смены спрайта. В конечном результате должен меняться существующий на экране спрайт на другой, подгрузив его из папки. Возможно ли это сделать? В документации sfml не нашел команды для смены спрайта на иной.

Comment: спрайты на экране не существуют, а рисуются, не понятно о чём вообще речь

Comment: короче файл грузится в Image, из него делается Texture, из текстуры спрайт

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего Вы уже умеете загружать текстуру в `sf::Texture`.

```
sf::Texture t;
t.loadFromFile("имя файла");
```

А потом выставить эту текстуру спрайту

```
sf::Sprite sp;
sp.SetTextur(&t);
```

Теперь решаем задачу. Сделайте две текстуры (или больше, или даже массив текстур). Загрузите в них сразу нужные текстуры. При старте приложения в спрайт загружается первая текстура. А когда пользователь нажимает кнопку, выставляем вторую

```
sf::Texture t1, t2;
t1.loadFromFile("имя файла1");
t2.loadFromFile("имя файла2");
sf::Sprite sp;
sp.SetTextur(&t1);
//......
sf::Event event;
while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
        switch (event.key.code) {
         case sf::Keyboard::W:: {
             sp.SetTextur(&t2);
             break;
         }
    }
}
// а тут где то отрисовка спрайта
window.draw(sp);
```